# Remove JsonObeject Before Android api lvl 19

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Hello i have one json

```
String  prev_string= [
        {
            "mac_address": "D3-D3-D3-D3-D4",
            "minor": "2333",
            "time": "11-12-2014 2:36 PM",
            "major": "4444"
        },
        {
            "mac_address": "D3-D3-D3-D3-D3",
            "minor": "45555",
            "time": "11-12-2014 2:36 PM",
            "major": "2322"
        }
    ]
JSONArray json= new JSONArray(prev_string);
json.remove(1);
```

Im need remove the second object, json.remove(1) work fine, but in android before lvl 19 dont work .remove, How do I can make it work?

Regards!

Comment: add the declaration of the json object and the delete method.

Comment: can you share how you declare your json array?

Comment: Hello guys, im update my question, for my variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, sort of surprising that it wasn't added until API 19. You could just define a utility method some where that iterates over the source object, and adds all elements to the new object (except for the specified index). Something like this:

```
public static JSONArray removeJsonObjectAtJsonArrayIndex(JSONArray source, int index) throws JSONException {
    if (index < 0 || index > source.length() - 1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    final JSONArray copy = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0, count = source.length(); i < count; i++) {
        if (i != index) copy.put(source.get(i));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right it is a method added starting from api 19. There is no easy workaround here.

**Two solutions:**

> Use another library to hold the Json objects.
>
> OR
>
> Create a new Json array and add objects to it one by one except the
>   one you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

before api level 19, the trick was to parse the object in a Collection, remove the item that you don't need and then create a new JSONArray with the constructor that takes a collection. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.util.Collection)) the documentation